# SQL CallablStatement - The index is out of range

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I'm using java servlets with database and I always get error with "The index 2 is out of range." I just want to send a parameters name and message from a form and through procedure save into database. Why I get this error message?

Add.jsp

```
<p>${result}</p>
    <form action="Servlet" method="post">
        <div class="comment-form">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="4">
            <p class="name">
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" value="${param.name}">
            </p>
            <p class="text">
                <label>Message:</label>
                <textarea name="message"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" name="btnComment" value="Add">
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Servlet.java

```
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String message = request.getParameter("message");
    if (name == null || name.trim().equals("")) {
        request.setAttribute("result", "Name missing!");
        return "Add.jsp";
    } else {
        try {
            con = comments.getConnection();
            synchronized (con) {
                stat = con.prepareCall("{CALL procAdd(?)}");
                stat.setString(1, name);
                stat.setString(2, message);
                stat.executeUpdate();
            }
            request.setAttribute("result", "Comment added.");
            return "Comments.jsp";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            request.setAttribute("result", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            return "Add.jsp";
        }
```

Procedure procAdd

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procAdd (
@Name VARCHAR (50),
@Message VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Comments(Name, Date, Message) VALUES (@Name, GETDATE(), @Message)
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the setter methods on `CallableStatement` returned by `Connection#prepareCall(String)`, assigns  the object you pass to the index of each `?` found in your `String`, starting at `1`. Since you only have a single `?`, you can only set that one. Your second setter call:

```
stat.setString(2, message);
```

will therefore fail and throw the exception you see.

Since your `PROCEDURE` has two parameters, you should be calling it like so

```
stat = con.prepareCall("{CALL procAdd(?, ?)}");
stat.setString(1, name);
stat.setString(2, message);
```